# Creating a drilldown menu in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, drilldown

I have a array of strings which look similar to:

"folder1/filea/x1.png", "folder1/fileb/x2.png", "folder2/folder3/filec/x3.png" .....

And my goal is to create a drilldown menu like: http://iwantaneff.in/repo/plugins/menu-nav/drill.down/index.html

In rails I have tried using the group_by method, but had no luck. 
essentially I need to create a folder structure like

1. folder1

   - filea

     - x1.png
   - fileb

     - x2.png
2. folder2

and so on.....

Any idea on where to start? I am having major difficulty approaching this problem. I have used the split method on each array so I get an array of arrays, but this does not seem to be getting anywhere. I think I need to use recursion to go through sub-trees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is simple) use recursion for parsing and inserting data

example  of parsing =>

```
   def parse(hash)
      hash.each do |k,v|
        files = v.select{|e| e.size == 1}
        hash[k] = {"files" => files.flatten} unless files.empty?
        dirs = v - files
        unless dirs.empty? 
          dirs = parse(dirs.group_by{|e| e.shift})
          if files.empty?
            hash[k] = dirs  
          else
            hash[k].merge! dirs
          end
        end 
      end
    end
```

for input

```
h = {:root =>  ["folder1/filea/x1.png", "folder1/fileb/x2.png","folder1/fileb/folder4/111", "folder2/folder3/filec/x3.png","folder2/folder3/filec/x4.png"].map{|e| e.split("/")}}

parse(h)
```

output will be

```
{:root=>{"folder1"=>{"filea"=>{"files"=>["x1.png"]}, "fileb"=>{"files"=>["x2.png"], "folder4"=>{"files"=>["111"]}}}, "folder2"=>{"folder3"=>{"filec"=>{"files"=>["x3.png", "x4.png"]}}}}}
```

Comment: Don't have enough rep to vote you up. But this is perfect! Thank you so much!